# React native: callback error in native module

Tags: reactjs, react-native

in my react native application, I'm calling a native module, which in return calls a callback function. The processing time of the native module is about 1-2 seconds. I've now seen the case that if I restart the ios simulator using cmd + R, and the callback from the native module has not yet fired, I get the following error stack:

- undefined is not an objects (evaluating 'cb.apply')

  - _invokeCallBack (MessageQueue.js:264)
  - applyWithGuard (error-guard.js:30)
  - guardReturn (MessageQueue.js:95)
  - invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:277)

Do you have any idea how to catch this? Can I check in my native module whether the callback function even exists anymore?

Thanks & Regards
Philipp

Comment: One addition: in XCODE, i get the following error: "Warning: Cannot find callback with CBID 21. Native module may have invoked both the success callback and the error callback."

Comment: Hi, I am experiencing exactly the same error when I execute the callback in my Bluetooth LE scanning method invoked directly after my application has started. However, it works sometimes and sometimes it crashes. I'll provide source code on demand.

Comment: One addition, I copy the callback parameter into a private object and execute it later meaning not in the function that receives the original callback parameter.